# Names from list to a set()

Tags: python, list, set

This is just a simpler version of what i need to do, but it doesnt work

I have this list of names:

```
liste = ['Bell,G.I.', 'Swain,W.F.', 'Pictet,R.', 'Cordell,B.', 
         'Goodman,H.M.', 'Rutter,W.J.', 'Bell,G.I.', 'Pictet,R.L.', 
         'Rutter,W.J.', 'Cordell,B.', 'Tischer,E.', 'Goodman,H.M.', 
         'Sures,I.', 'Goeddel,D.V.', 'Gray,A.', 'Ullrich,A.', 
         'Ullrich,A.', 'Dull,T.J.', 'Gray,A.', 'Brosius,J.', 'Sures,I.', 
         'Bell,G.I.', 'Selby,M.J.', 'Rutter,W.J.', 'Ullrich,A.', 'Dull,T.J.', 
         'Gray,A.', 'Philips,J.A. III.', 'Peter,S.']


ex_set = set()

for i in liste:
    ex_set.add(i)
    
print(ex_set)
```

and I'm trying to get all the names into a set, where i am able to separate each name.
but when i print the ex_set, i only get some of the names

```
['Philips,J.A. III.', 'Tischer,E.', 'Cordell,B.', 'Pictet,R.L.', 'Goodman,H.M.', 'Sures,I.', 'Ullrich,A.', 'Peter,S.', 'Gray,A.', 'Selby,M.J.', 'Brosius,J.', 'Goeddel,D.V.', 'Pictet,R.', 'Swain,W.F.', 'Dull,T.J.', 'Rutter,W.J.', 'Bell,G.I.']
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: A `set` only keeps unique elements.

Comment: You just need to do `set(liste)` instead of looping through the list

Comment: Your input has several duplicates. Adding them to a set only keeps one copy of each.

Comment: "i only get some of the names" Which names are missing?

Comment: oh i didnt know it would remove duplicates automatically, thought i had to do it manually

Comment: The last printed output in your post is in fact a list (not a set). Please post the actual output of your code so that we can help. The current code in your post does what you claim to want it to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other members mentioned in comments: `set` - collection of unique data. That means that any duplicates will be removed on convertion/creation.

Also use of `for in` expression is redundant in your case as `list` may be converted to `set` just calling a `set(list)`.